# Switching directly to specific virtual desktop in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I've been forced to use windows and I'm severely missing possibility to switch directly to specific virtual desktop, done within 100ms. 'Simple' approach: "go to multitasking view, press combo windows_key-f12-num3-esc, and then simply left_key to switch to the 1 screen left" is not acceptable solution. What I'm after is say using F15 for desktop 2, etc (as F15 is that number 2 on Microsoft ergonomic 4000 keyboard ;) )

I've found multiple solutions and documentation pages, most of them either unreachable or with update: "does not work anymore".

I've read about autohotkey, which I'm not sure I will be able(allowed) to use. Was it solved by Microsoft somehow natively? Powershell or anything? Is it possible?

Comment: Virtual Desktops in Windows do not survive a restart. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @John - they *still* haven't figured out how to make that survive through a restart? What happens to apps that were open on other Desktops? Do they all just get shunted unceremoniously back to the main desktop? btw, I'm guessing the OP has been forced onto Win from Mac, where all of this has 'just worked' for over a decade; including simple key commands to switch to different numbered Desktops/Spaces & survives reboot.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry for puzzling question. I meant in year 2022, since most of "how-to"s are really old, mostly outdated. So I'd like to know, if there was any progress made, and feature is more mature in windows now.

Comment: @Tetsujin from linux actually, where it works without glitch for at least 2-3 decades ;) I don't expect, that it will be flawless, but I'd like to create some workaround for me to have work experience close to what I'm used to. So if virtual desktops does not survive reboot (didn't expect that), I guess I can create powershell script to create them at startup. That should be easy. But I didn't find way how to switch directly to specific screen without installing 3-rd party sw.

Comment: Ah, OK. Wild [& stupidly overkill] idea… Run macOS on Intel. Install Parallels & a Windows VM. Switch on Coherence mode. Now all your Windows apps behave as though they were running directly inside macOS & can be assigned to Spaces as desired, with key commands to each Space. Survives reboot without even shutting down the Windows VM.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, but I'm afraid we'd have to aim for simpler solutions. It's corporation. If solution contains word "install" or "configure", it's probably a problem. I used VirtuaWin in ~2010 and it worked almost 100%, and allegedly autohotkey works as well. But if I have decisive power / can install stuff myself, ideally I'd remove windows as optimal solution to these problems. Not being able to do this, I'm looking for windows-native solution. If all fails, I can indeed at least program keyboard firmware to have faster way to type ineffective key combinations...

Comment: No worries - I didn't think it would be particularly practical unless you already have a slew of spare Macs you could just throw one together with. It's actually how I run Windows here. I have a building full of Macs & no actual 'Windows PC' anywhere, one nix for my networking. So I always think in terms of VMs on top of Mac for my own convenience - whether it's running Win-specific tasks or just playing games I can't get on the Mac, there's a VM for everything; often that I remote into so I'm not even burning my own Mac's CPU cycles ;)